# Why typescript don't see an error when i pass obviously wrong (according to type of prop) function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a props type for component Canvas:

```
interface CanvasProps {
  draw: (ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) => void
  width?: number
  height?: number
}
```

when I'm passing such a function, I don't get any type error

```
 <Canvas draw={()=>'a'} />
```

I have predictable behaving of typescript if I pass any other type of data into 'draw'. For example, I get error when pass 'a' or true.

But why it doesn't see an error when I pass obviously wrong function?

Comment: The type on a function's parameters is there to make sure that valid data must be passed into it. Ie, if someone calls `draw`, they must pass a CanvasRenderingContext2D in. It doesn't try to verify that the function does anything with that data. So the function you provided is good as far as typescript is concerned.